# How get one element from Selector

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy, selector

I have this code in python 2.7

```
        for product in  response.xpath('//*[@class="s-result-item s-result-card-for-container s-carded-grid celwidget "]'):

            print product
```

the result of every product is

```
<Selector xpath='//*[@class="s-result-item s-result-card-for-container s-carded-grid celwidget "]' data=u'<li id="result_18" data-asin="B00DO53DSY'>
```

i want to know how can i extract each data like **data-asin**

i tried

```
product.xpath(//data-asin).extract()
```

and this one

product.css("Selector::attr(data-asin)").extract()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my own question

```
product.css('li::attr(data-asin)').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an xpath, you need to extract the li with the attribute `data-sin`:

```
product.xpath("./li/@data-sin").extract_first()
```

*data-asin* is an attribute not a tag so you need the `@` syntax.

Comment: I believe it should be `product.xpath(".//@data-asin")` in the 2nd case.

Comment: @paultrmbrth, yes  if you had multiple tags, the second example I prefaced with  *if the li was the only tag*,  i.e what pulls an attribute from a tag, there could be other `data-asin attributes not in an li so I was not recommending to just look for the attribute. I removed it altogether to avoid confusion